# TFS 2017 Rest API - Get Approval For a Release after the release is approved

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to be able to log who approved a release when the release is running.  We have audit requirements to prove who is the gatekeeper of the environments. Here are the order of events:

1. A release gets triggered and sits and waits for approval.
2. A different user approves the release
3. The release completes.

As the release is happening I want to be able to log who the approver was.  What we found is if you use the Approvals API you can you get the ApprovalID.  The problem is this can only be performed in between Steps 1 and 2.  After a release has been approved you can no longer get the ApprovalID, its empty.

We have then gone an looked at the information for the specific release and there is not any data in the Approver area.  Even in the documentation sample responses you see that the data just isn't there.  Is there anything I can do in 2017 to get this information?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/rm/releases?view=tfs-2017

```
$RecentReleaseUrl = $TFSCollectionPath + $TFSProjectName + "/_apis/Release/approvals?releaseIdsFilter=$RecentRealease&api-version=3.2-preview.2"

$RecentReleasedefinition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $RecentReleaseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$ApprovalID = $RecentReleasedefinition.value.id
```

Comment: You want this to run as inline script or after release completed manually ?

Comment: Yes, as an inline script to keep track of who approved the release to the current environment.  i'll end up sending the info to ELK during the release to track and report for audit purposes.  I'm going to attempt the solution below today and will give an update.

Comment: In that case,the function should be eaiser than what i posted, Let me know if you want me to share that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amit Baranes got us close, I've updated his answer with our solution.

```
function DefinitionHelper.GetReleaseApprover
{
    $Local = "False"

    #If running locally then use local values, when running on the build server use the env variables
    if ($Local -eq "True")
    {
        $ReleaseID = "16734"
        $Environment = "TEST"
    }
    else
    {
        $ReleaseID = $env:RELEASE_RELEASEID
        $Environment = $env:RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTNAME
    }

    # Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $Username,$TFSToken)))

    #Url to get details for Release
    $ReleaseUrl = $TFSCollectionPath + $TFSProjectName +"/_apis/Release/releases/"+$ReleaseID+"?api-version=3.2-preview.2"
    Write-Host "ReleaseUrl :"$ReleaseUrl
    #Rest-API call to get details for Release
    $ReleaseDetails = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $ReleaseUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
    #Get the current environment
    $EnvironmentDetails = $ReleaseDetails.environments | where name -eq $Environment
    #Get the approval
    $ApproverDetails = $EnvironmentDetails.preDeployApprovals.approvedBy
```

}

Comment: This was close but this wasn't it.  What you have above show us the Snapshot approver, that is who can approve the environment, not who actually approved a particular release.  The data is in the actual release object in preDeployApproval.approvedBy object.  We thought that object was empty because it looks empty when looking at the json response, but its there.

Comment: Glad i could help,if you find this helpful please edit my answer and accept it.

Comment: @gperrego Great, It's nice to learn new approaches every day.